# How to convert string array by getting numeric value from comma separated string variable?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

For example I have a string variable like this:

```
string data = "12,false,13,false,14,false,15,false";
```

I'd like to convert it to a string array by filtering numeric value only

```
string[] datas=["12","13","14","15"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using [`string.Split()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [`char.IsDigit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0ddtxh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and linq:

```
string[] datas = data.Split(',').Where(s => s.All(char.IsDigit)).ToArray();
```

How it works:

- splits the string by `,`
- filters (`Where`) the resulting string by checking that
- every character in a string is a digit (`All`, `IsDigit`)
- converts the resulting enumeration into an array (`ToArray()`)